# Eclipse - Groovy 2.3 / 2.4 - Issues with Spock compiler plugin Spock 1.0.0-groovy-2.4

Tags: java, eclipse, grails, groovy, spock

I have been trying to fix this using multiple options as much as I understood but at no success, so finally thought to ask for help here.

I not much familiar with groovy and its related plugins for eclipse.

I have this project this which used groovy 2.3 compiler. But that setting was changed in our project by another developer to use groovy 2.4 compiler.

So I started getting errors in eclipse like

```
Groovy:Unexpected problem with AST transform: The Spock compiler plugin cannot execute because Spock 1.0.0-groovy-2.4 is not compatible with Groovy 2.0.7
```

I had groovy 2.0 and 2.3 compiler feature installed before this. So I un-installed 2.0 compiler feature and installed groovy 2.4 compiler feature version.

So now I have 2.3 and 2.4 groovy compiler features for my eclipse.

But somehow it still show that `2.0` version in the error mentioned above.

Also I tried using `switching compiler` in eclipse, but now I cannot see any option for `2.4` it just shows that I have `2.3` version and no other compiler is present.

I restarted eclipse and my computer a couple of times but no luck.

Please if anyone encountered problem this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The different Groovy compilers are different plugins. Make sure that you have the "Groovy Compiler 2.4 Feature" installed.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant - groovy 2.4 compiler feature, updated my question

Comment: You mean that that's what you installed? What's the version shown in Installation Details?

Comment: Installation details says - `Groovy compiler 2.4 feature` and  under `Groovy-Eclipse Feature` it has `Groovy compiler 2.3 feature`

Comment: Right, and there should be a version on each of those, something like 2.9.`n`.xx-`date`.

Comment: It is `2.9.2.xx201508121448-e45`